# Multiple ng-options dropdowns not working properly?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, ng-options

I am new in angular using ng-options to display values in drop downs.
 i have total 4 drop down lists in one form. If i select first
 dropdown's  value and then goes to second drop down to select any
 value then first  drop down's value will vanished. same happens for
 third and four. at last only fourth dropdown's selected value i can
 see.
And on success form i want to display pop up. below is my code for dropdowns and script.

```
<select ng-model="empInfo" ng-options="emp.candidate_name for emp in names4" class="span2">
</select>                       

<select ng-model="empInfo" ng-options="emp.company_name for emp in names" class="span2">
</select>                       

<select ng-model="empInfo" ng-options="emp.designation_type for emp in names1" class="span2">                                           
</select>


var app = angular.module('myApp', ['720kb.datepicker']);
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.adhr.adnacgroup.com/ADHRM/companyJson.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.names = $scope.names = response.data.service;
    });

    $http.get("http://www.adhr.adnacgroup.com/ADHRM/designationJson.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.names1 = $scope.names1 = response.data.service;
    });

    $http.get("http://www.adhr.adnacgroup.com/ADHRM/finalCandidatesJson.php")
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.names4 = $scope.names4 = response.data.service;
    });

    $scope.insertInfo = function(info) {
        $http.post('addconfirmation.php?confirmation=',{
            "referal_code":info.referal_code,
            "candidate_id":info.candidate_id,
            "company_id":info.company_id,
            "designation_type_id":info.designation_type_id,
            "address":info.address,
            "joiningdate":info.joiningdate,
        }).success(function(data1) {
            if (data1 == true) 
            {
                getInfo();          
                $('#empForm').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign different `scope` on each dropdown. Having same `ng-model` on each `select` tag then one overrides the other.

e.g. :

```
<select  ng-model="empInfo1" ng-options="emp.company_name for emp in names">
<select  ng-model="empInfo2" ng-options="emp.company_name for emp in names">
```

Comment: bro its working but now another problem is coming. i actually want to print selected value and store it after submit. but now another 2 things are not working?

Comment: you might create an other question for your problem. also do not forget to provide a detailed description about the problem and a demonstration via plunker/jsfiddle etc. would be extra helpful to get an answer.

Comment: no problem thanks alot for your help. i'll ask this question seperately